# Django-admin overriding inlined broken save-like button (grappelli-like overriders)

Tags: django, django-admin

I decided to style my django-admin interface. Both django-grappelli and django-admin-bootstrapped are really convincing.

Grappelli : http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

django-admin-bootstrapped : https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped

My models.py contains a `Parent` model and a `Child` model linked by a foreign key. And my admin.py contains a `ChildInline(admin.TabularInline)`  class.
I noticed that, while the inline save button works with the original django-admin admin interface, it does not with grappelli, nor django-admin-bootstrapped, probably nor any other admin overrider. The save button seems to be broken.
Idem for the "Save and continue editing" and "Save and add another". *A contrario*, the  `Parent` "delete" button works.

Why ?

PS : I'm using django 1.7.1 and django-admin-bootstrapped 2.2.1

Comment: What version of Django and django-admin-bootstrapped are you using?

Comment: I'm using django 1.7.1 and django-admin-bootstrapped 2.2.1

Comment: Then I suggest you open up an issue on github for django-admin-bootstrapped.

Comment: I am struggling with inline deletion within parent model in django (1.9) admin with bootstrap or with django-grappelli (2.8.1) also (in 2016). It simply does not work (in today's Chrome or Firefox)! It looks like a js failure !?